# Is it possible to `skip` execution while other epic is running?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm a beginner in RxJS so sorry if this doesn't make sense.

The current flow in time looks like this:

```
REMOVE_USER -----------------------> SUCCESS
---------------GET_DEVICE--->SUCCESS--------
```

The high-level goal is to skip fetching device when user is being removed.

**Oversimplified epics:**

```js
const getDeviceEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType('GET_DEVICE_REQUEST'),
  mergeMap(() => from(service...).pipe(
    mapTo({ type: 'GET_DEVICE_SUCCESS' }))
  ))

const removeUser = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType('REMOVE_USER_REQUEST'),
  mergeMap(() => from(service...).pipe(
    mapTo({ type: 'REMOVE_USER_SUCCESS' }))
  )
)
```

How would I approach that?

I'm not sure if I can somehow add e.g. `takeUntil(removeUserAPICall$)` to device app. Or perhaps check if `REMOVE_USER_REQUEST` has been fired and then wait for `REMOVE_USER_SUCCESS` to continue.

Comment: have you considered setting some flag, e.g. `removingUser: true` on the store, when you receive `REMOVE_USER`? And then ignoring `GET_DEVICE_REQUEST` if its true.

Comment: That's actually what I do now - it's not as elegant as there are many many devices to be fetched so I'm setting `devicesBeingLoaded: [...ids]`.

I was just curious if there's a way to do it only with observables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potentially, you could achieve that with **[windowToggle](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/windowToggle/)**:

[image: windowToggle]

In your case **"on"** is `REMOVE_USER_SUCCESS` and **"off"** is `REMOVE_USER_REQUEST`.

So we'll be listening to `GET_DEVICE_REQUEST` between `REMOVE_USER_SUCCESS` and `REMOVE_USER_REQUEST`.

Note that we'll have to start with our filter open, by prepending `startWith(void 0)` to the "on" stream.

E.g.:

```js
const getDeviceEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType('GET_DEVICE_REQUEST'),
  windowToggle(
    action$.pipe(ofType('REMOVE_USER_SUCCESS'), startWith(void 0)),
    ()=>action$.pipe(ofType('REMOVE_USER_REQUEST')
  ),
  mergeMap(() => from(service...).pipe(
    mapTo({ type: 'GET_DEVICE_SUCCESS' }))
  ))

const removeUser = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType('REMOVE_USER_REQUEST'),
  mergeMap(() => from(service...).pipe(
    mapTo({ type: 'REMOVE_USER_SUCCESS' }))
  )
)
```

* *warning: written in a notepad*

Yet, imho, it's also fine to have a flag on the store (maybe, as an indication of the state).

More about pausing and muting streams in my article "[Pausable Observables in RxJS](https://medium.com/@kddsky/pauseable-observables-in-rxjs-58ce2b8c7dfd)".

--

Hope this helps